# Running SQL queries and getting back the result on deployed software

Tags: c#, sql

We update the software manually every couple of weeks (by copying over files).For the database we get their backup, apply the changes and hand it back over.In the meantime when we do a bug fix it's usually to do with the database and no code change is needed, but we have to message back and forth with the client's IT people, emailing SQL scripts and asking them to send back the result, which is cumbersome.How could I go about automating this?

We use SSDT schema compare for the updates then we hand it over.  Afterwards, we have no connection to their db so troubleshooting becomes hard and we have the clients IT people in between as proxy. I want to publish the scripts to some sort of server and have client software periodically check that location and run them in order.

Comment: Why not use a screen sharing/remote desktop software?

Comment: Can't you write (generate) migration SQL scripts and integrate them with an installer program?

Comment: can't use RDP because of some client policies

Comment: @makaroni _" I want to publish the scripts to some sort of server and have client software periodically check that location and run them in order"_ And what's your particular problem with doing just that? You can deploy a service running in the background with your software to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I go about automating this?

The usual way is to use a database design tool, that is capable of generating DB migration scripts from the old DB schema version to the newer version.

The generated migration script should be running as part of your software update, or sent to your customers' IT staff to run it.

Comment: yes we use SSDT schema compare for the updates then we hand it over.afterwards we have no connection to their db so troubleshooting becomes hard and we have the clients IT people in between as proxy. I want to publish the scripts to some sort of server and have client software periodically check that location and run them in order

Comment: @makaroni You should probably add all that information to your original question to receive better answers.